# Ideas to hang five polycarbonate squares to ceiling

Tags: ceiling, hanging, plastic, support

I have five plastic (polycarbonate) squares that I need to hang / attach them to the ceiling (concrete). They can touch the ceiling, or have little (maximum 2 inches) gap between the square and the ceiling.

They weight around 1.5 lbs / 600 grams each, and are 8x8x1.4 inches / 200x200x35 mm.

Not only they are polycarbonate, but they are smooth, so adhesives don't stick to it easily. Also, there is not a single hole that I could use as a support.

Picture a smooth polycarbonate square.

They are going to be hang / attached to the ceiling, so there is gravity pulling them downwards too.

Ideally, attach in a way that it is not very hard to remove and with no to little damage to the squares and ceiling.
I tried these foam adhesives, they fell after a few days unfortunately, mainly because they did not adhere to smooth polycarbonate.

Ideas of what I can do? I could attach something (a wire? piece of metal?) to the squares using silicone, and go from there. Has to be something aesthetically acceptable.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93156/discussion-on-question-by-igorjrr-ideas-to-hang-five-polycarbonate-squares-to-ce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Neodymium, Rare earth magnets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BDFPX6K).

Very strong, one on each corner will be enough to hold 1.5 lbs.

Use the silicone that you have tested on the panels to attach a magnet to each corner of the panels and let cure for a day. Take the other magnets for the ceiling and turn them so they stick or attract the magnets on the panels and place them on the magnets already adhered to the panels so that they're holding together (one side attracts and one side repels).

Now you can use a clear instant-grip adhesive like [loctite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076H9BRGT)  to attach the magnets to the ceiling.

While the ceiling magnets are being held onto the panel magnets, place a little dab of adhesive on each magnet and then place the panel in position on the ceiling.

You may need to take a long strip of tape and tape the panel up to the ceiling until the adhesive sets.

When it's time to remove them, a putty knife or painters scraper should pop the magnets off.

Comment: Thank you, in fact I started that a while ago, but the problem is removing the magnets from the ceiling later. The magnets are small and it will be difficult to remove. Any idea on how that should be done?

Comment: Also, in fact these squares they light up, so there is some electrical component inside, having a very strong magnet like that might not be a good idea. I could use a ceramic magnet, but the question about removing them later from the ceiling remains. It seems it will be painful and messy.

Comment: I addressed removing them in the last line of my answer.  They should pop of with a scraper, you may need to take some denatured alcohol or other solvent and a scrubbing pad to remove any residue left on the ceiling from the adhesive. I would not consider that to "painful and messy"* If you are concerned do a test on some out of the way concrete wall*.  I do not think the magnets will be a problem with the electricity. But you easily test that before hand as well.

Comment: Is this adhesive you suggested actually easier (I mean, less messy, less damages) to remove than if I use silicone to attach the magnets to the ceiling? Because with silicone the residue left is usually a stain that is very hard to remove.

Comment: @igorjrr i can not answer that,  that is why i suggested you do a test, test a few options. **It is concrete**, is it painted ?  If it is painted then you can sand off the residue with emery clothe and touch up the paint. I can **NOT** give you an **EASY BUTTON**.

Comment: I understand, I was just asking, maybe you have more experience with this adhesive than I have with silicone. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up doing this: instead of attaching magnets directly to the ceiling, I attached a small electrical box metal flat cover to the ceiling using silicone. This metal box also has a hole for screw if silicone fails or you prefer screws over silicone adhesive. The mais reason is that this allows me to move the squares/tiles around the metal area for better positioning of the squares. The magnets were attached to the squares/tiles using silicone as well. It is working great. If the squares are swiveling with wind for example, a double sided tape on the magnet will make it stay in place.

Comment: Nice. Thinking outside the box.